# JQuery: choose drop down from list of selected inputs

Tags: jquery

So I have this code:

```
jQuery('div[class="someClass"] :input:not(:button)').each(function() {               
    if (input type is drop-down) {
        //do something
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this).attr("value",null);
    }
}
```

I have selected all inputs except buttons in a specific class. Now for each input selected, if the input is a drop-down list I wish to do something, otherwise I wish to set the input to blank, which the last line does. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
if ($(this).is('select')) {
    //do something
} else {
    $(this).val('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should ignore all input type button and button elements.

```
$('.someClass').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is('select')) {
        //do something
    } else if ($(this).not('input[type="button"]') && $(this).not(':button')){
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```